# Python xml - Add tags in the same line with parent tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, element, elementtree

I am trying to make an MyXml.xml file by parsing other Source.xml file. Current structure of MyXml is:

```
<tag atrib="true" atrib2="false" atrib3="1" atrib4="7">
    <tag1 txt="CONTENT">
        <tag2 name="Category">1</Field>
        <tag3 name="Wallet"> </Field>
        <tag4 name="Increase">1</Field>
        <tag5 name="Text">
            <div />
        </tag5>
    </tag1>
</tag>
```

But my  output should be like this (tags of tag5 should be in same line):

```
   <tag atrib="true" atrib2="false" atrib3="1" atrib4="7">
        <tag1 txt="CONTENT">
            <tag2 name="Category">1</Field>
            <tag3 name="Wallet"> </Field>
            <tag4 name="Increase">1</Field>
            <tag5 name="Text"><div><h2>SomeTxt</h2></div></tag5>
        </tag1>
    </tag>
```

current code is this:

```
MDroot = minidom.Document()
tag = MDroot.createElement('tag')
MDroot.appendChild(tag)

# Other tags
root = ET.Element('tag')
tag1 = ET.SubElement(root, 'tag1', txt= 'CONTENT')

ET.SubElement(tag1, "tag2", name='Category').text = "Heading"
ET.SubElement(tag1, "tag3", name='Wallet').text = ' '
ET.SubElement(tag1, "tag4", name='Increase').text = 1

tag5 = ET.SubElement(tag1, "tag5 ", name='Text')
div = ET.SubElement(tag5 , "div",)
root1 = ET.Element(tag5)
root1.insert(1, div)
```

But this code always creates normal xml structure with parenting. Any idea how can I put those in the same line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in xml lines are **NOT** important!

```
<tag5 name="Text"><div><h2>SomeTxt</h2></div></tag5>
```

has the **same** meaning as:

```
<tag5 name="Text">
    <div>
      <h2>SomeTxt</h2>
    </div>
</tag5>
```

So just ignore the lines.

Comment: I know that in general it is not important at all, problem is that I have to import that xml into some external program which has problems with reading regular file